# How to assign programatically a field to a paragraph bundle

Tags: 8, entities, paragraphs

I'm developing a module to extend paragraphs module.

The idea is that the users can assign a description field to paragraphs bundles.

I have create a module, and also I have create the file `field.storage.paragraph.parrados_description.yml` If I go to `admin/reports/fields`  or if I try to assign the field to a paragraph bundle with UI I can see it in the list of fields.

But what I want to make it's create a form with paragraphs bundles checkboxes, so the administrator / site builder can check the bundles to assign the field to it when the user submit the form.

But I don't find any method to assign a field to a bundle.

Thanks

Oskar

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use the field UI.

Comment: Because it's not the same assign the field to 3 bundles or to 30 bundles, and if it's a UI it means that there is a method that make it by code, so I don't want to reinvent the wheel, I want to use the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't find any method to assign a field to a bundle.

This is not one single method, it's a bit more complicated than that. Example for the body field in a node bundle. First create the bundle specific field config referencing the existing field storage:

```
  $field_storage = FieldStorageConfig::loadByName('node', 'body');
  $field = FieldConfig::loadByName('node', $type->id(), 'body');
  if (empty($field)) {
    $field = FieldConfig::create([
      'field_storage' => $field_storage,
      'bundle' => $type->id(),
      'label' => $label,
      'settings' => ['display_summary' => TRUE],
    ]);
    $field->save();
```

Then add the field to the display modes:

```
    // Assign widget settings for the 'default' form mode.
    entity_get_form_display('node', $type->id(), 'default')
      ->setComponent('body', [
        'type' => 'text_textarea_with_summary',
      ])
      ->save();

    // Assign display settings for the 'default' and 'teaser' view modes.
    entity_get_display('node', $type->id(), 'default')
      ->setComponent('body', [
        'label' => 'hidden',
        'type' => 'text_default',
      ])
      ->save();

    // The teaser view mode is created by the Standard profile and therefore
    // might not exist.
    $view_modes = \Drupal::entityManager()->getViewModes('node');
    if (isset($view_modes['teaser'])) {
      entity_get_display('node', $type->id(), 'teaser')
        ->setComponent('body', [
          'label' => 'hidden',
          'type' => 'text_summary_or_trimmed',
        ])
        ->save();
    }
  }
```

Code example from https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_add_body_field/8.5.x